# Problem importing vue-pdf-embed in a Larvel Vue 3 project: ERR_ABORTED 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pdf, vuejs3

I am trying to display a PDF file in vue component
using the **vue-pdf-embed** package. (https://github.com/hrynko/vue-pdf-embed?ref=madewithvuejs.com)

I have installed the package using `npm install vue-pdf-embed --save`

However, as soon as I include the `import VuePdfEmbed from 'vue-pdf-embed'` in my component, the application fails with the following error message:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-pdf-embed.js?t=1681405592025&v=c4ae62d5 net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Outdated Optimize Dep)
```

This is the code for my component:

```
template>
<div>
    <h1>PDF Preview</h1>
    <!--
        <vue-pdf-embed :source="pdfDocumentSource" />
    -->
</div>
</template>

<script>

   import VuePdfEmbed from 'vue-pdf-embed'

   export default {
   components: {},

   props: {
     pdfDocumentSource: {
        type: String, // path on server including filename
        required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong or this a bug? Has anyone used this package?
Any suggestion for any other PDF viewer package that I can use -- I just need to display PDF files which are stored in Laravel Storage.